# Post a message on user's wall with Twitter-OAuth-iPhone

Tags: iphone, twitter

I use the bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone. How do I post message on user wall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
- (NSString *)sendUpdate:(NSString *)status
```

function. status is the message which you want to post.